2 handle delta kitchen faucet water oozes from cold base when hot water is running
Delta 2 handled kitchen faucet, when hot water is running the base of the cold water faucet (under the handle) oozes water. It does not leak when the cold water is on. Only hot. The faucet also has a sprayer diverter.

Please post photos

This is probably the spindle seal on the cold valve.
This is usally a rubber "O" ring and is fairly easy to replace (turn off the cold water supply to this valve first)
